# order TableLayout content by specific column

Tags: android, tablelayout

Good day to all.

Is there some way to order the TableLayout content by a specific column?

I need to order the content according to user selection from a spinner.
Example if the user chooses to order the table by "name" the column name is arranged in ascending order.

The rows contain TextViews in which said content is saved, and the content is populated via a database.

Is there an easier way to order the content other than having to re-open a connection to the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i can think of is to create a java object for your table row entries, putting all your objects into a list and comparing them using something like this:

```
Collections.sort(nodeList, new Comparator<DataNode>(){
 public int compare(DataNode o1, DataNode o2){
     if(o1.degree == o2.degree)
         return 0;
     return o1.degree < o2.degree ? -1 : 1;
 }
});
```

It would be easier to re-open a connection to the database. You have to redraw your TableLayout in all cases.

Comment: Good idea, I really don't like the idea of having to re-open the database connection, but as you may also think, that seems to be the only way.  Thank you very much for your answer!